# NodeJS organize loop with repeated records

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table where I store the sales of certain products. I need to fetch the records by client id.

I did like this:

```
public async getData(clientID: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return await client
        .scan({
          TableName: "dbSales",
          FilterExpression: "contains(clientID, :clientID)",
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":clientID": clientID,
          },
        })
        .promise()
        .then(async (response) => {
          let data = [];
          
          for (let i = 0; i < response.Count; i++) {
            if(data.filter(product => product.productId == response.Items[i]['productId']) != undefined){
                const resultData = await this.getProduct(response.Items[i]['productId']);
                data.push(resultData);
            }
          }

          return {
            status: 200,
            data: data,
          };
        })
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
          throw error;
        });
    } catch (e) {
      throw new HttpError(500, e.message);
    }
  }
```

There it will get all the records with that customer id, and then through a condition it will get the product name of each record it found, through another function (getProduct), with the repetition loop.

The problem is that I'm getting a lot of repeated results, i.e. for the same product id and customer.

I need that when there is more than one record in dbSales with the same customer id and with the same product id, it returns me only one result for those records.

That is, one row for each record that contains the same customer ID and product ID.

This is generating a long delay in the search for data, as I only need which products a particular customer has purchased, without the information being repeated when he has more purchases of the same product.

Comment: Using scan should be avoided, if possible. Consider organizing your table so that you can query by customer ID. Also, filter on an array doesn't return undefined. It will return empty array if no items pass the filter's test.

Comment: @jarmod My table is organized like this: [https://ibb.co/rcNrcvc](https://ibb.co/rcNrcvc), how do you indicate?

Comment: [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on pk=clientId and sk=productId would allow you to efficiently query for all items with a given clientId. If a given client can repeat buy the same product, which is presumably true, then you'd get multiple items with the same product ID. Obviously you want to avoid re-fetching that product from the product table in that case so simply track which products you've already fetched e.g. in a Map.

Comment: @jarmod Unfortunately I can't set pk=clientId as the current pk is used in other queries. :/

Comment: Read about DynamoDB indexes. GSI is a secondary index, and you can have multiple.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, but this incurs additional costs and is not my objective. In the current code would there be any other solution?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent items with the same customer ID and product ID being written to the table in the first place? Or are you trying to simply de-duplicate these items after they are returned by scan? Those are 2 very different things. If it's the latter, then DynamoDB isn't going to de-duplicate your table's items for you. You need to do that. Typical solutions include 'remembering' that you previously saw a given customer ID and product ID pair, e.g. in a set or map.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid duplicate items in the first place then consider a [conditional put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) or [uniqueness constraints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/).

Comment: @jarmod Yes I need to de-duplicate the scan return. Do you have a working example for this?

Comment: Examples at [How to remove duplicate objects in array based on 2 properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402325/how-to-remove-duplicates-objects-in-array-based-on-2-properties)

Comment: @jarmod Owww! Man, you saved my day! Thank you so much for your tip, it worked 100%! God blesses!

Comment: Instead of editing the question to include the answer, it's encouraged to answer your own question and mark that as the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
This keeps it out of filters for unanswered questions, and you get a reputation boost too. :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear that helped. As Eric suggested, if you can, add an answer to this question and then accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Problem solved! Solution:**

The solution presented by our friend **@jarmod** solved my problem, in a simple way.

```
let result = response.Items.filter((e, i) => {
    return response.Items.findIndex((x) => {
    return x.productId == e.productId}) == i;
 });

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if(data.filter(product => product.productId == result[i]['productId']) != undefined){
        const resultData = await this.getProduct(result[i]['productId']);
        data.push(resultData);
    }
 }
```

Proposed solution: [How to remove duplicates objects in array based on 2 properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402325/how-to-remove-duplicates-objects-in-array-based-on-2-properties)